# Make two <div> same height with mootools 1.12

Tags: mootools, html

How to make two  with same height with mootools 1.12 when there are images in the second one which doesn't have set attribute "height" in their code?

```
<div id="box-1"></div>
<div id="box-2">
 <img src="..." />
 <img src="..." />
 <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.extend({  
    equalize: function(){
        maxHeight = [];

        this.each(function(el){
            maxHeight.push(el.getSize().size.y);
        });

        this.setStyle('height', Math['max'].apply(Math, maxHeight));
    }
});

$$('li').equalize(); // in your case $$('#box-1, #box-2')
```

Obviously triggered when `onLoad` not `onDomReady`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/mE6G3/

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements to Oskars code:

1. By implementing `Elements`, the method can only be called on an Element collection (and the `getSize` and `setStyle` functions are always available).
2. Using `map()` to get all heights.
3. Returning the collection, so the method can be chained.

So the code becomes:

```
Elements.implement({
    equalHeight: function(){
        // Get height for all elements
        var heights = this.map(function(el){
            return el.getSize().y;
        });

        // Get maximum height
        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);

        // Set maximum height to all elements
        return this.setStyle('height', maxHeight);
    }
});
```

And this could even be written as:

```
Elements.implement({  
    equalHeight: function(){
        return this.setStyle('height', Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function(el){
            return el.getSize().y;
        })));
    }
});
```